# How can I create another partition without losing my operating system?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I bought a HP laptop with an Intel i5 processor. There is Windows 7 on it.

I have:

- C partition with 450 GB
- D partition with 36 GB ("Recovery")

I want to create another partition in `C:`. How can I create this partition without losing my operating system?

Comment: This question is very vuage and undreadable in it's current format. I'd advise you to edit your question to try and clarify what you want. Do you want to create a new partition? Do you want to see if you can delete the D:\ and assign the space to C:\?

Comment: @tombull I tried to clarify it – does that make more sense now?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a partition inside of C:, C: itself is a partition, you can resize C: using [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) and then add a 3rd partition and label it F: or whatever you like, or you can delete D: and expand C: to fill the space.

BE WARNED, When doing anything with your partitions back up the partion table first and becuase your going to be playing with things that can format a disk , make sure you have a backup of any data you need before hand

Comment: I recommend to do a defragmentation before repartitioning. If you are resizing the partition it is better to push everything in one place and keep everything organized.

Comment: Also I would suggest to have a good source of uninterrupted power supply. Though you are using a laptop, this wont be a worry, still it is better to have batteries charged. Midway failure to this process can cause hell of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a waste of time, but I would take the time to backup your entire hard-drive before proceeding. You can do this before defragmentation and maybe even after as well (before doing the actual partitioning.)

The first thing I would do is to defrag your HD. [JKDefrag](http://www.kessels.nl/JkDefrag/) is the one I use. It works very well for me. What this will do is organize your hard disk to make sure all of your clusters are grouped closer together so that you can have a larger amount of free space to work with. The application that comes with a simple GUI as well. Just double click and let it be for a while.

After the defragmentation is over, you can partition your hard drive using the disk management tools that come with Windows 7. You can use third party software if you like, but I don't find anything wrong with the tools that come with your OS. [Here are instructions on how to re-partition your hard drive, straight from the manufacturer.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Can-I-repartition-my-hard-disk)

Basically, after you get into your disk management screen (right click 'My Computer' > Manage > Disk Management), you will right click your `C:` partition and click on the `Shrink Volume` or similar option in the menu. Enter the amount of space you want to shrink by, and then let it do it's work.